# Data Combination in dataset

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, recommendation-engine

I have a dataset of student in XLSX format from semester One to Eight. I'm trying to combine all the data of a specific student in one place. I'm Using Pandas
here is the complete dataset.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CTL1m-avkmpMTm67m4c9iq7WGf8EeP9c/view?usp=sharing

I tried to concatenate the rows with same registration number.

It's a picture of dataset. below this i have same registration number again. so I want to combine all the data through registration number:

Comment: Please share a copy of the dataset that can be copied into a text editor

Comment: here is the complete dataset  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CTL1m-avkmpMTm67m4c9iq7WGf8EeP9c/view?usp=sharing